# Line Intensity Profile From Image

Tags: image-processing, image

I can get line profiles from images using imagej but it would be nice to be able to do this in my mathematica notebooks.

I found this

http://library.wolfram.com/examples/intensityprofiles/

after some google searches and it is exactly what I want to be able to do. However it seems they removed this package. I cant seem to figure out how to do this in v 9.0.

Anyone know how to do this?

Edit: I added a picture to make it more clear what I'm talking about. Its important that I can take an arbitrary (diagonal) line and that mathematica interpolates between pixels in a way that makes sense.

Sorry if my formatting is off, this is my first post.

[image: I'm basically trying to do this]

UPDATE: This is what I think I'm going to use to do what I want. Obviously the display isn't made, and details need to be sorted out, but ImageValue interpolates automatically and seems like the Built-In to use. Thanks for the help everyone.

```
  img = Import["http://i.imgur.com/szcChXh.png?1"]
    (*First Argument of ImageProfile is the arc length along the line profile,
    incremented in steps of 1/(npts-1)*)
    (*Second Argument of ImageValue is the parametric form of a line, incremented in       
    steps of 1/(npts-1)*)

    ImageProfile[img_, x1_, y1_, x2_, y2_, npts_] := 
     Table[{N@((i - 1)/(npts - 1)) Sqrt[(x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2], 
       ImageValue[
        img, {x1 + (x2 - x1) (i - 1)/(npts - 1), 
         y1 + (y2 - y1) (i - 1)/(npts - 1)}]}, {i, 1, npts}]
    pt1 = {500, 300};
    pt2 = {600, 600};
   Show[img, Graphics[{Red, Thick, Line[{pt1, pt2}]}]]
    ListPlot[ImageProfile[img, pt1[[1]], pt1[[2]], pt2[[1]], pt2[[2]],1000], Joined -> True]
```

Comment: closely related: [Band Intensity Quantification](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42947/5478) :)

Comment: The problem with this is that it doesn't seem to be able to handle diagonal lines, which is the main reason i wasn't sure how to do it just from the ImageData matrix.

Comment: I agree but you have not said what is your main concern, I'm just linking the thread :)

Comment: @kuba You can test with [this one](http://newton.umsl.edu/run//nano/5102D120.png) or similar diffraction images.

Answer (score 14):

#### Edit:

I've included the code from [Bresenham's line algorithm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45753/5478) of [halirutan](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/187/halirutan) which is used to get positions of pixels of interest, `ImageValue` is more convenient but maybe one don't want to do any interpolations. Also couple of minor improvements added, I forgot `Refresh[...,None]` at the beginning. Looking forward for any sugesstions :)

[image]

```
img = ColorConvert[Import["http://newton.umsl.edu/run//nano/5102D120.png"],
                   "Grayscale"]

Deploy@With[{opt = Sequence[Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 450, BaseStyle -> {18, Bold}, 
             AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, ImagePadding -> 55, FrameLabel -> {"|pi-x|", 
             "Graylevel"}, FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, 
            {{#1, "x"}, {#2, "y"}} &}}]},
  DynamicModule[{x, y, w, pos, data, profile, label, linegraphics, sectionplot, fix, 
                 moveboth, bb, bresenham},
   Dynamic[Refresh[

    Panel@Grid[{{
        Show[img, linegraphics],
        Column[{
          sectionplot,
          "",
          moveboth,
          bb
          }, Center, BaseStyle -> {18, Bold}]
        }}, Alignment -> Top]

    , None]],
   Initialization :> (
     dim = ImageDimensions@img;
     x = Round[dim/2];
     y = Round[2 dim/3];
     fix = True;
     pos[] := bresenham[IntegerPart@x, IntegerPart@y];

     profile[] := With[{p = pos[]}, 
                   SortBy[Transpose@{Norm /@ N[# - x & /@ p], PixelValue[img, p]},
                          First]];


     linegraphics = Graphics[{
        Yellow, Dynamic@Line[{x, y}], AbsolutePointSize@8, Orange, 
        Dynamic@Point[{x, y}],            
        Locator[Dynamic[x, {(w = y - x) &, (x = #; If[fix, y = x + w];) &, None}], 
                Appearance -> None],
        Locator[Dynamic@y, Appearance -> None],
        Text[Style["x", 18], Dynamic[x + {20, 0}]],
        Text[Style["y", 18], Dynamic[y + {20, 0}]]}];

     moveboth = Grid[{{Checkbox[Dynamic@fix], "move both with x."}}];

     bb = ButtonBar[{"Set vertical" :> (x = Round[dim .5]; y = Round[dim {.5, .7}];), 
                     "Set horizontal" :> (x = Round[dim .5]; y = Round[dim {.7, .5}])}];

     sectionplot = Graphics[{
                    Dynamic[{Line[#], AbsolutePointSize@3, Red, Point[#]} &@profile[]]},
                    PlotRange -> {All, {0, 1}}, opt];

     ClearAll[bresenham];
     bresenham[p0_, p1_] := Module[{dx, dy, sx, sy, err, newp},
      {dx, dy} = Abs[p1 - p0];
      {sx, sy} = Sign[p1 - p0];
      err = dx - dy;
      newp[{x_, y_}] := With[{e2 = 2 err}, {
       If[e2 > -dy, err -= dy; x + sx, x], 
       If[e2 < dx, err += dx; y + sy, y]}];
      NestWhileList[newp, p0, # =!= p1 &, 1]];
     )]
  ]
```

Comment: Points are not equally spaced, the plot is distance of pixel from $x$ vs graylevel. If you need you may use `Interpolation` etc.

Comment: Of course you can unscope the `profile` and use it however you need.

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much.

Comment: @bshev I'm glad you like it. Please take a look at an update, it may be more user friendly now.

Answer (score 7):

You could use `ImageTransformation`:

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
line = {{150.`, 406.`}, {271.`, 156.`}};

ImageTransformation[img, 
 line[[1]] + #[[1]]*(line[[2]] - line[[1]]) &, {100, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, DataRange -> Full]
```

If you want raw pixel values instead of an image, use `ImageData[transformResult][[1]]`, to get the pixels in the first (and only) line of the result image

Comment: I think he wants intensity profile.

Comment: Thank you. I think that this is a good place for me to get started.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov: I always thought an intensity profile was the sampled intensity values along a path (in this case, a line). Maybe I misunderstood the term. What would be your definition?

Comment: @nikie I just meant he wants the actual plot ;-) `ListLinePlot[Mean /@ First[ImageData[%]]]`

Comment: Nice idea. I wouldn't have thought to use `ImageTransformation` for this.

Answer (score 6):

According to an example here:[`ImageValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageValue.html), you could use an extension of this perhaps:

```
 ImageValue[yourimage, Table[{i, i}, {i, .5, 10, 1}]];
```

This takes the values of the diagonal pixels in the image and outputs them as a list - you could then interpolate this for your intensity plot.

Extending it to an arbitrary line shouldn't be too much of a leap!

Comment: This suggestion actually turned out to be the most useful in terms of what i wanted the program to actually do. ImageValue uses interpolation automatically. Thank you