# How to implement Bresenham’s algorithm as a system of equations?

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning, computational-geometry, code-golf

[Bresenham's line drawing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm) is usually implemented via [loops](http://members.chello.at/~easyfilter/bresenham.html). But in *Mathematica* we can take advantage of its ability to solve Diophantine equations. From educational viewpoint it is quite interesting to write Bresenham in a form suitable for `Solve` or other superfunction. Such implementation also potentially can be very terse and sufficiently efficient for most practical applications.

I have implemented Bresenham for the first octant and obtained general solution via reflections (code for version 10):

```
Clear[bresenhamSolve];
bresenhamSolve[p1_, p2_] /; 
   GreaterEqual @@ Abs[p2 - p1] && MatchQ[Sign[p2 - p1], {1, 1} | {1, 0}] := 
  Block[{ab = First@Solve[{p1, p2}.{a, 1} == b], x, y}, {x, y} /. 
    Solve[{a x + y + err == b /. ab, -1/2 < err <= 1/2, {x, y} \[Element] Integers, 
      p1 <= {x, y} <= p2}, {x, y, err}]
   ];
bresenhamSolve[p1_, p2_] /; 
   Less @@ Abs[p2 - p1] && MatchQ[Sign[p2 - p1], {1, 1} | {0, 1}] := 
  Reverse /@ bresenhamSolve[Reverse[p1], Reverse[p2]];
bresenhamSolve[p1_, p2_] := 
  With[{s = 2 UnitStep[p2 - p1] - 1}, 
   Replace[bresenhamSolve[p1 s, p2 s], {x_, y_} :> s {x, y}, {1}]];
```

Of course this code cannot be called terse.

This implementation is identical to [halirutan's implementation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/45806/280):

```
lines = DeleteCases[Partition[#, 2] & /@ Tuples[Range[-30, 30, 6], {4}], {p_, p_}];
Length[lines]
bresenhamSolve @@@ lines == bresenham @@@ lines
```

> ```
> 14520
>
> True
> ```

Visualization:

```
p1 = {2, 3}; p2 = {20, 13};
Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, RGBColor[203/255, 5/17, 22/255]}], 
  FaceForm[RGBColor[131/255, 148/255, 10/17]], 
  Rectangle /@ (bresenhamSolve[p1, p2] - .5), {RGBColor[0, 43/255, 18/85], Thick, 
   Line[{p1, p2}]}}, GridLines -> (Range[#1, #2 + 1] & @@@ Transpose[{p1, p2}] - .5), 
 Frame -> True]
```

> [image: plot]

```
Manipulate[Row[{Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, RGBColor[203/255, 5/17, 22/255]}], 
     FaceForm[RGBColor[131/255, 148/255, 10/17]], 
     Rectangle /@ (bresenhamSolve @@ Round[pts] - .5), {RGBColor[0, 43/255, 18/85], Thick,
       Arrow@pts}}, GridLines -> ({Range[-50, 50], Range[-50, 50]} - .5), Frame -> True, 
    PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-20, 20}}, ImageSize -> 500], 
   Column[Round@pts]}], {{pts, {{-11, -13}, {8, 15}}}, Locator}]
```

> [image: manipulate]

Checking symmetry:

```
n = 20; center = {0, 0};
perimeterOfSquare = {x, y} /. 
   Solve[{x, y} \[Element] 
     RegionBoundary[Rectangle[{-n, -n} + center, {n, n} + center]], {x, y}, Integers];
ArrayPlot[SparseArray[
  Rule @@@ Tally[# - center & /@ 
     Flatten[bresenhamSolve[center, #] & /@ perimeterOfSquare + n + 1, 1]], {2 n + 1, 
   2 n + 1}], Mesh -> True, PlotRange -> {All, All, {1, 9}}, ClippingStyle -> Red, 
 PixelConstrained -> True]
```

> [image: arrayplot]

Timing comparison with halirutan's implementation:

```
p1 = {2, 3}; p2 = {2001, 1300};
Timing[bresenhamSolve[p1, p2];]
Timing[bresenham[p1, p2];]
```

> ```
> {0.171601, Null}
>
> {0.0312002, Null}
> ```

My question:

**Is it possible to write general implementation without splitting it into special cases and with good performance?** Instead of `Solve` one can use other superfunction(s).

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use the Bresenham algorithm? Wouldn't it be much simpler and more efficient to use floating point arithmetic? I mean, the Bresenham algorithm was useful when floating point operations were expensive and it payed to replace them with several integer instructions. On today's hardware, and in an interpreted language, that is almost certainly not the case anymore. Are you targeting a Raspberry Pi? (+1 for nostalgia, though)

Comment: @nikie I used "Bresenham" more as a brand-name for the method of rendering lines, I'm not interested *specifically* in restricted to integers operations only algorithm. I'm looking for any efficient analytical solution leading to the same result. My motivation is both educational and finding a way to implement *subpixel* "Bresenham".

Answer (score 6):

If you only want the pixel coordinates of a line, that can be done much simpler:

```
Clear[pointsOnLine]
pointsOnLine[{p1_, p2_}, nPts_] := 
 Array[Round[p1 + # (p2 - p1)] &, nPts, {0., 1.}]
pointsOnLine[l_: {p1_, p2_}] := 
 pointsOnLine[l, Round[Max[Abs[p1 - p2]]] + 1]
```

The result is the same as your algorithm:

[image]

but it's much faster:

```
p1 = {2, 3}; p2 = {2001, 1300};
RepeatedTiming[bresenhamSolve[p1, p2];]
RepeatedTiming[bresenham[p1, p2];]
RepeatedTiming[pointsOnLine[{p1, p2}];]
```

> {0.0777, Null}
>
> {0.0120, Null}
>
> {0.000919, Null}

**ADD**: If you want *exactly* the same results as the original `bresenham` function, you have to force `Round` to round .5 up, instead of to the nearest even integer. Easiest way to do this is to just add a small epsilon to every value:

```
epsilon = 10^-10;
Clear[pointsOnLine, p1, p2]
pointsOnLine[{p1_, p2_}, nPts_] := 
 Array[Round[p1 + # (p2 - p1) - epsilon] &, nPts, {0., 1.}]
pointsOnLine[{p1_, p2_}] := 
 pointsOnLine[{p1, p2}, Round[Max[Abs[p1 - p2]]] + 1]
```

Comment: That is cool but not identical to `bresenham`: try `p1 = {0, 0}; p2 = {20, 10};`, `p1 = {-1, -2}; p2 = {17, -38};`. Also check the code under words "Checking symmetry:" in the question - the pattern is entirely different.

Comment: That's because `Round` rounds .5 towards the nearest even integer. You can use e.g. `rnd = Ceiling[# - .5] &;`. That gives a symmetric result, but it will still sometimes round different than `bresenham`, since the calculation is done in machine precision.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the image processing functionality in Mathematica.  Is there a way to do something like `ClusteringComponents`, but locally, i.e. compensate for the image being darker/brighter in some places?  I'm trying to segment a brain into gray matter  / white matter.

Answer (score 2):

### Original Bresenham

Starting with [the code by nikie](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96468/280) I was able to implement *original* Bresenham using **exact arithmetic**:

```
Clear[pointsOnLine]
pointsOnLine[{p1_, p2_}] := 
 With[{d = p2 - p1}, 
  p1 + IntegerPart[#] + Round[FractionalPart[#]] & /@ 
   Array[# d &, Max[Abs[d]] + 1, {0, 1}]]
```

Unfortunately I haven't found a way to reproduce original Bresenham with floating point arithmetic.

Proof that this implementation is is identical to [halirutan's implementation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/45806/280):

```
lines = DeleteCases[Partition[#, 2] & /@ Tuples[Range[-30, 30, 6], {4}], {p_, p_}];
Length[lines]
pointsOnLine /@ lines == bresenham @@@ lines
```

> ```
> 14520
>
> True
> ```

Timings:

```
p1 = {2, 3}; p2 = {2001, 1300};
RepeatedTiming[bresenhamSolve[p1, p2];]
RepeatedTiming[bresenham[p1, p2];]
RepeatedTiming[pointsOnLine[{p1, p2}];]
```

> ```
> {0.15, Null}
>
> {0.027, Null}
>
> {0.025, Null}
> ```

---

### An alternative to Bresenham

Here is simpler and more efficient implementation which produces a pattern with the same symmetry as Bresenham's using  another rounding scheme:

```
pointsOnLine[{p1_, p2_}] := 
 With[{d = p2 - p1}, p1 + # & /@ Round[Array[# d &, Max[Abs[d]] + 1, {0, 1}]]]
```

The pattern:

```
n = 20; center = {0, 0};
perimeterOfSquare = {x, y} /. 
   Solve[{x, y} \[Element] 
     RegionBoundary[Rectangle[{-n, -n} + center, {n, n} + center]], {x, y}, Integers];
ArrayPlot[SparseArray[
  Rule @@@ Tally[# - center & /@ 
     Flatten[pointsOnLine[{center, #}] & /@ perimeterOfSquare + n + 1, 1]], {2 n + 1, 
   2 n + 1}], Mesh -> True, PlotRange -> {All, All, {1, 9}}, ClippingStyle -> Red, 
 PixelConstrained -> True]
```

> [image: plot]

Here is `Manipulate` which allows to explore the differences between `bresenham` and different implementation of `pointsOnLine`:

```
Manipulate[Row[{Graphics[{{EdgeForm[], FaceForm[GrayLevel[.6]], 
      Rectangle /@ (pointsOnLine@Round[pts] - .5)}, {EdgeForm[{Thick, Darker@Red}], 
      FaceForm[], Rectangle /@ (bresenham @@ Round[pts] - .5)}, {Black, Thick, 
      Arrow@pts}}, GridLines -> ({Range[-20, 20], Range[-20, 20]} - .5), Frame -> True, 
    PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-20, 20}}, ImageSize -> 500], 
   Column[Round@pts]}], {{pts, {{-11, -13}, {15, 0}}}, Locator}]
```

[image: output]