# How to `Framed` the element which is in a approximate connectional line between any two position in non-square matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, image, filtering

As you see,I can `Farmed` the diagonal element:

```
mat = RandomInteger[20, {13, 17}];
pos = Graphics[Line[{{1, 1}, a = Dimensions[mat]}]] // 
        Rasterize[#, ImageSize -> Max[a]] & // ImageCrop // 
      Binarize[#, Mean[#] < 0.99 &] & // Thinning // 
    PixelValuePositions[#, 1] & // 
   DeleteCases[#, _?(#[[1]] > a[[1]] || #[[2]] > a[[2]] &)] &;
MapAt[Framed, mat, pos] // TableForm
```

[image]

But I think the method is too ugly.Anyone can give a more beautiful programme?

And I can `Framed` the element which is in a approximate connectional line between any two position by Image-Tool:

```
mat = RandomInteger[5, {7, 18}];
pic = mat // Image[#, ImageSize -> Large] & // ImageAdjust
```

[image]

We can get the `mask` with Image-Tool like this:
[image]

And we crop it

[image]

So we get the result:

```
pos = Position[mask // ImageData, 1];
MapAt[Framed, mat, pos] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

But we can find a bug in this method

[image]

So we miss a frame in the result.And we cannot build a function like `FramedInLine[{1,5},{6,15}]`,Because of the use of Image-Tool.Anybody can help me?

Comment: Do you want to do this? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96214/193

Comment: Or rather http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45753/bresenhams-line-algorithm/

Comment: @belisariushassettled How do you find this topic?

Comment: The name of the algorithm is `Bresenham's`. A very common topic in computer graphics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dims = {13, 17};
mat = RandomInteger[20, {13, 17}];
cols = Flatten@ Reverse[Ordering[#, 1] & /@  ImageData[
          ColorConvert[ImageResize[Graphics[Line[{{1, 1}, dims}]], dims], "Grayscale"]]];
pos = Thread[Transpose[{cols, Range@Length@cols}] -> k] /. k -> {Bold, Red};
Grid[mat, ItemStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, pos}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Hello Dr. ,Actually your link has solve my problem.Thanks again~