# Taking a diagonal cut through a matrix

Tags: plotting, matrix, interpolation

Lets say I have a gaussian data matrix, e.g.

```
x=GaussianMatrix[20]
```

I would like to take a cut through this matrix at a 45 degree angle to get its intensity profile, like this:

[image]

rather than a straight line cut in the x or y coordinates. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: ``Diagonal[x]`` to get the main diagonal, or ``Diagonal[x, k]`` to get elements on the $k$-th diagonal.

Comment: Thank you! What if I want to take the cut at a different angle? not necessarily at the diagonal?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are using a matrix and not a two dimensional Gaussian PDF? Anyhow, to get a different angle, you could use the [Bresenham algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm). There is at least [one solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45753/bresenhams-line-algorithm?noredirect=1&lq=1) here on SE. Or use something like: ``Binarize[Rasterize[Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {2, 3}}]], RasterSize -> 40]]``.

Answer (score 3):

```
x = GaussianMatrix[20];
```

Construct an [interpolation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListInterpolation.html):

```
j = ListInterpolation[x, {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, InterpolationOrder -> 3];
```

Plot at arbitrary angle:

```
With[{α = 0.3},
  Plot[j[t*Cos[α], t*Sin[α]], {t, -1, 1}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
x = GaussianMatrix[20];
MatrixPlot[x]

Manipulate[
 ListLinePlot[Diagonal[x, i], PlotRange -> {{0, 40}, {0, 0.002}}],
  {i, -Dimensions[x][[1]], Dimensions[x][[2]], 1}
 ]
```

[image]