# Obtain polygons describing all intersections of many polygons

Tags: image-processing, computational-geometry, geometry

I have 6894 polygons describing zones in a state plane (i.e., cartesian) coordinate system. Most are not very complex, and I believe none have holes. A random example is

> Polygon[{{351633., 564236.}, {351681., 562612.}, {351663., 
>      562555.}, {351699., 561341.}, {348792., 561268.}, {348733., 
>      564168.}, {351633., 564236.}}]

1. How can I test whether these polygons have holes?
2. I want a new set of polygons that describe all areas in which one or more of these polygons intersect, and I need to know which polygons cover each of these regions. So, in the new set the region where polygon A is unintersected is one region, the region where A and B intersect is another region, the region where A, B, and C intersect is another, and so on. Any of these "regions" in the new set is not necessarily connected; for example, one could imagine a wide polygon being split in half by a thin one, producing two unintersected regions. In such cases I need a list of closed polygons (associated, as the other polygons, with the appropriate members of the domain set).

I have no idea how to do this mathematically, and it would be very cool to see a solution if someone has one. But on a more practical level I suspect that I can do this at high precision using image processing.

Here is an example of what is going on:

```
polygons = Get["https://s3.amazonaws.com/tblackburn/stack_exchange/polygons-sample"];
(* my polygons are benign, but beware what you "Get" from the internet! *)
n = 100;
Riffle[ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Rescale[Range[n + 1]], RandomChoice[polygons, n]];
Graphics[Prepend[%, Opacity@.5], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Is there a way to scale a set of colors such that I can calculate what color each intersection would be, and such that the color is guaranteed to be unique? And then use the morphology suite of functions on a rasterized image to generate new polygons? I need the new polygons expressed in the same coordinate system, and I need the vertices to be as accurate as possible -- so the rasters would have to be quite large I think.

Or, is there some other way to obtain the result I am after?

I have 32 CPUs and 244 GB of memory to throw at this.

Comment: I love _"such that I can calculate what color each intersection would be"_. Sounds like magic :)

Comment: @belisarius I have seen [image processing magic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42947/band-intensity-quantification) from *you* before :)

Comment: Oh! But I was sober that day! I almost remember ...

Comment: You could use a binary encoding: assign each shape a colour that has exactly 1 nonzero bit, rasterize each on a black background, then use `ImageAdd`. But you can only distinguish up to 24 shapes.

Comment: Another problem with an image processing approach is that if two edges intersect at a small angle you will get a chain of disconnected pixels: http://i.stack.imgur.com/TmEtp.png

Comment: Just a note that the colour you will get for overlaps depends on the ordering of the polygons. Try evaluating `Row[Graphics /@ Map[{Opacity[0.5], #, Disk[]} & {{Red, Yellow, Blue}, {Yellow, Blue, Red}}, {2}]]` and you'll see what I mean. A way out would be to `GatherBy` color and then `Sort`ing and look at the colour spectrum you get and whether it matches the topological properties you are after. The colour issue has been observed in [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47809/how-can-i-get-the-color-of-overlapping-disks-to-be-equal-in-any-order/)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805333/determine-if-polygon-has-a-hole

Comment: `polygons[[9]]` includes each perimeter point twice, so it is **all** hole.

Comment: If a boundary has no self intersection then it cannot have any holes.  That would require multiple boundaries.

Answer (score 3):

Well, since you bragged about computing power...

```
Clear@findIntersections;
findIntersections[polyGroup__] := Module[{reg},
  reg = RegionIntersection[
    Sequence @@ 
       DiscretizeRegion[#, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
        Method -> "DiscretizeGraphics", AccuracyGoal -> 10, 
        PrecisionGoal -> 10] & /@ polygons[[polyGroup]]];
  If[RegionDimension@reg > 0, 
   AppendTo[
    intPolygons, {Fold[regDiffPatch, reg, intPolygons[[All, 1]]], 
     poylGroup}]];
  ]
```

...you can just enumerate all the possible intersections and try them one by one, in reverse order:

```
intPolygons = {};
res = findIntersections /@ Most@Reverse@Subsets[Range[3]] // Quiet

Row[Column[{#, Graphics@polygons[[#]]}] & /@ {1, 2, 3}]
Column /@ intPolygons // Row
Row[{Show[intPolygons[[All, 1]]], Graphics@polygons[[{1, 2, 3}]]}]
```

> [image: Polygon list]

The quality makes me cry and if I add one more polygon MMA just won't calculate the last intersection, and I don't even know why, because whatever the output is, it takes so long to appear that I never waited enough to see it.

**But, hey**, with that computing power you can just crank the Accuracy and Precision goals to over 9000 and you're probably good to go!

Here's the best a 2012 notebook could do:

> [image: Polygon list with 4]

Here's the missing piece of code form the main function. It's just a bunch of silly heuristics to avoid some of the `RegionDifference` limitations (in many cases it won't compute and won't tell you why):

```
regDiffPatch["", reg2_] := "";
regDiffPatch[reg1_, ""] := reg1;
regDiffPatch[reg1_, reg2_] := 
 If[(Abs[Area@RegionUnion[reg1, reg2] - (Area@reg1 + Area@reg2)]/
     Area@RegionUnion[reg1, reg2]) < 0.01
  , reg1
  , Check[If[Area@RegionIntersection[reg1, reg2] == Area@reg1
    , ""
    , If[(Area@RegionIntersection[reg1, reg2]/Area@reg1) < 0.01, reg1,
      RegionDifference[reg1, reg2]]], RegionDifference[reg1, reg2]]
  ]
```